# Cosine similarity - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I've read through a handful of similar posts, but haven't found an exact duplicate for my issue.

I'm working on calculating cosine similarity for tfidf values, and am getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I understand that this is basically saying that 2 values were expected and there are more than 2 values being fed through, resulting in an error.  But I'm not sure how to move forward from here.

Here's the full code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel

def find_similar(tfidf_matrix, index, top_n = 5):
    cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix[index:index+1], tfidf_matrix).flatten()
    related_docs_indices = [i for i in cosine_similarities.argsort()[::-1] if i != index]
    return [(index, cosine_similarities[index]) for index in related_docs_indices][0:top_n]

corpus = []
for doc in nlp.pipe(df['TIP_all_txt'].astype('unicode').values, batch_size=9845,
                        n_threads=3):
    if doc.is_parsed:
        corpus.append([n.text for n in doc if not n.is_punct and not n.is_stop and not n.is_space])
    else:
        corpus.append(None)

tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,3), min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english')
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform([content for doc, doc in corpus])

for me_index, item in enumerate(corpus):
        similar_documents =  [(corpus[index], score) for index, score in find_similar(tfidf_matrix, me_index)]
        me = corpus[me_index]

        document_id = me[0].split("/")[1].split(".")[0]

        for ((raw_similar_document_id, title), score) in similar_documents:
            similar_document_id = raw_similar_document_id.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]
            writer.writerow([document_id, me[1], similar_document_id, title, score])
```

and error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-8522d91e96f8> in <module>()
      8 
      9 tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,3), min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english')
---> 10 tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform([content for doc, doc in corpus])
     11 
     12 for me_index, item in enumerate(corpus):

<ipython-input-75-8522d91e96f8> in <listcomp>(.0)
      8 
      9 tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,3), min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english')
---> 10 tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform([content for doc, doc in corpus])
     11 
     12 for me_index, item in enumerate(corpus):

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: What should this `[content for doc, doc in corpus]` list comprehension do? Where `content` should come from? ` Why do you want to unpack `doc, doc`? How do you plan to unpack two values if `corpus` might be populated with `None` values? (see `corpus.append(None)`)

Comment: @soon Each row in my df has 1-2 paragraphs of text, which have been converted to lists of tokens (originally I was lemmatizing the text, but changed to tokens because I thought that might be causing issues).  I only populate with None values to ensure the text maintains it's position in the df.